# jqgrid inline searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, inline-editing

I have a jqgrid that I am performing an inline edit on. I am using the textarea instead of text. How do I submit the data once I'm done editing the cell. "Enter" works on text and obviously doesn't on textarea since it creates a new line.

This is a snippet from my code

```
grid4 = $('#CaseNotes').jqGrid({
   ...
   { name: 'Note', index: 'Note', width: 650, align: 'left', sortable: false, 
      editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: '5', cols: '100' }
   },
   ...
   onSelectRow: function (id) {
      if (id && id != lastsel) {
         grid4.restoreRow(lastsel);
         lastsel = id;
      }
      grid4.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, '', '', '', '', reload);
   },
   editurl: '@Url.Action("EditCaseNote", "CaseNote")',
   ...
});

//function to reload the grid
function reload(id, result) {
   grid4.setGridParam(
      {
         url: '@Url.Action("DisplayCaseNotesGrid", "CaseInfo")',
         datatype: 'json'
      }
   ).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you mean "inline editing" instead of "inline searching". Because you can't use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you have to include some additional button in the [Navigator toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) which call [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) method. You can either add the corresponding row manually with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) or use [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) method.

Comment: I'm sorry I corrected my post. I meant inline editing. So if I have the extra button do I still need to have this grid4.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, '', '', '', '', reload); ?

Comment: @brasewel: The `editRow` is needed to initialize the inline aditing. By the way I would prefer another form of the call: `grid4.jqGrid('editRow', id, {keys: true, afterrestorefunc: reload};`. If you need to call `reload` after saving you should use `{afterrestorefunc: reload}` option in the call of `saveRow` method too.

Comment: Oleg I used grid4.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#casenotes_pager', { edit: true, add: false }); and removed the onSelectRow. How do I call my reload function to refresh the grid after the controller returns?

Comment: @brasewel: I think it should be like `grid4.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#casenotes_pager', { edit: true, add: false, editParams: { keys: true, afterrestorefunc: reload } });`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oleg's advise I was able to solve this. Here is my code incase anyone runs into a similar problem. I removed my refresh function since I no longer needed it.

```
grid4 = $('#CaseNotes').jqGrid({
...
{ name: 'Note', index: 'Note', width: 650, align: 'left', sortable: false, 
  editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: '5', cols: '100' }
},
...
onSelectRow: function (id) {
   if (id && id != lastsel) {
      grid4.restoreRow(lastsel);
      lastsel = id;
   }
   grid4.jqGrid('editRow', id, { keys: true, afterrestorefunc: reload });
},
...
});
//Adds the button to the pager
grid4.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#casenotes_pager', {
   caption: 'Save Case Note',
   buttonicon: 'none',
   onClickButton: function () {
      //calls the saveRow function
      grid4.jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel,
      {
         url: '@Url.Action("EditCaseNote", "CaseNote")'
      }
      );
      //refreshes the grid
      grid4.setGridParam(
      {
         url: '@Url.Action("DisplayCaseNotesGrid", "CaseInfo")',
         datatype: 'json'
      }
      ).trigger('reloadGrid');
   }
});
```